# Aggregate Urls based on first path

Tags: sql, presto

Let's say I have a table with a bunch of URL's in it

```
             URL                      Some_Value     
------------------------------------------------
0 www.google.com/help/experience          3
1 www.google.com/help/tutorial            1
2 www.google.com/signup                   0
3 www.google.com/signup/form              199
4 www.google.com/signup/believe           3 
5 www.google.com/signup/new               1
6 www.google.com/welcome/kr               15
7 www.google.com/help/location            2
8 www.google.com/store/shirts             1
```

And I want to aggregate values to the first path in the URL, how would I go about doing that?

so it would look like this:

```
       URL             agg_value
www.google.com/help.   6
www.google.com/signup  193
www.google.com/store.  1
www.google.com/welcome 15
etc...
```

I know in presto that substr() would be the best way to do this, but I do not know how to use substr to stop at the second '/'

```
select substr('www.google.com/store/shirts',1,5)
```

Comment: Please also share what you tried?

Comment: Try `regexp_extract(URL, '^[^\/]*\/\w+')`

Comment: This works, but is there a way to not remove a hyphen '-'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression can be used to get the first folder in the URL path.

```
SELECT regexp_extract(URL, '^[^\/]*\/[\w-]+') AS URL, sum(Some_Value) AS agg_value
FROM mytable
GROUP BY 1
```

Regex pattern:

- `^` - start of URL string
- `[^\/]*` - any chars except `/`
- `\/` - `/` char
- `[\w-]+` - one or more word character `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `_` and hyphen char `-`